# Why am I allowed to create multiple instances of Singleton, even though its constructor is private?

Tags: swift, singleton, swift-playground

The code below is a singleton example from a book where I study Swift. Isn't the aim of creating singletons having only one object of that type? In the playground, I've been able to create multiple `GameManager`s (`var a = GameManager()`, `var b = GameManager()` etc.)

By the way I am aware that there is only one `defaultManager` object and it cannot be changed due to it being static and constant (let). But I couldn't get the use of a private constructor since I am able to create multiple `GameManager`s.

```
class GameManager {
    static let defaultManager = GameManager()
    var gameScore = 0
    var saveState = 0
    private init() {}
}
```

Comment: This post: http://krakendev.io/blog/the-right-way-to-write-a-singleton explains the reasoning and theory very well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Playground can access the private constructor because Swift lets you access anything that is `private` as long as your code is in the same file with the private code.

Since everything typed directly into the playground editor's window is considered a single file, you can access anything from everywhere.

Once you put the code outside Playground, though, the constructor's visibility would be enforced, preventing your code from creating instances of `GameManager` as intended.

Comment: Not everything in a playground is a single file, you can open the package that comprises the playground file or use the Navigator (left panel) to add additional files or resources. Put the class in a file in the Sources folder (create it if it's not there) and then the singleton will work fine.

Comment: @KennethBruno Cool, that's nice to know! I meant the stuff you type directly into playground's editor, though. I edited the answer to be more specific about it.